# Workflow for interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface, workflow

I'm slowly starting to understand the basics of syntax of C#, but there's so much more to programming than that. I've been wondering about how to efficiently use interfaces without hindering the coding process.

By setting up an interface for a class you're making a commitment. Before implementing all members of your interface, the code won't compile. This could make it inconvenient to test programs, having to either temporarily disable the interface, or create shoddy placeholder methods for all classes that use it. Neither seems like a good practice to me. I could of course implement the interface only afterwards, but wouldn't that kind of defeat the purpose? Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't get your problem. When you tell Visual Studio to implement the interface it creates all the needed methods/properties for you. That they all throw a `NotImplementedException` shouldn't be a hindrance since you won't test/call them before you implement them anyway. Or do _I_ miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer -> is you have to implement all the Interface members in the classes.

Basically visual studio or other tools are providing auto implement interface that will implement 'throw new NotImplementedException()'. So you can test your behavior and implement other members.

Interface is used for abstraction as well as to enforce the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

to test interfaces without proper implementations of their required methods, I refer you to the combination of NullObject pattern, and "MOQ".

if you create a MOQ of an interface, you won't need to have methods you don't call, defined.
Moq will effectively create a nullobject function at runtime for your interface.

if you don't want to use MOQ, you can create a "NullObject" Pattern for your interface yourself, and simply use "no action" for all methods, and then implement them one at a time.

I would suggest using MOQ, in a unit testing setting, as you should be doing that anyway, and should always have a unit test for your implementations, for regression testing purposes.

```
public interface IExample {
   int ExampleMethod1();

   void DoStuff();
}

public class UnitTest{
   public method Test(){
      Mock<IExample> example = new Mock<IExample>();
      example.Setup(mock => mock.ExampleMethod1()).Returns(1);


      var actualResult = example.ExampleMethod1();
      Assert.AreEqual(1, actualResult);
}
}
```

This unit test should run.